# Integrating Solr + Hadoop and Nutch + Hbase on Amazon Web Services and Local

Tags: hadoop, solr, amazon-web-services, hbase, nutch

I have a machine on Amazon Web Services and I am trying some search features on it. I have installed Nutch and Hbase on my AWS machine.

I have crawled wikipedia.org as an example and the crawled data is stored at Hbase at cloud.

I want to install Solr and make a search on it. I did not installed my system as a cluster because I just want to make some research i.e. how can I use it etc.

My question is where Hadoop stands at this system(I did not install Hadoop yet)? Is it logical to install Hadoop  and Solr my local computer. Also my next challenge will be how can I communicate my local computer with AWS computer.

Comment: Check out CloudSearch (aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/) to be able to search in scale (much simpler than managing your clusters)

Comment: @Guy my purpose is to get a knowledge for such kind of things.

Comment: I didn't go into more details as you asked about Hadoop and CloudSearch is not based on Hadoop specifically. It does scale nicely, but it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Nutch you already have Hadoop, which handled your crawling and parsing.
You can take the data produced by Nutch and push it into to Solr for indexing.

Comment: I have installed nutch and crawled a website into Hbase. I don't have Hadoop yet. My main question is how Hadoop Map Reduce Jobs will integrate with Solr indexes/jobs. Is there any code example or explanation for it?

Comment: Even if you install the native Hadoop library or your O/S, Nutch will use it to crawl and parse the content it finds, yielding data into the crawl directory. Indexing the resulting data into Solr is a relatively quick process that does not use or require Hadoop.